Inner product on $V$ such that $\langle e_1,e_2 \rangle =2$

Find the inner product on $V$ such that $\langle e_1,e_2 \rangle =2$.

I tried using the matrix method:
$$ \langle e_1,e_2 \rangle = (1,0) \, A \, (0,1)^T.$$
From this, we would get $A$ as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
k & 2 \\ 
k & k 
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $k$ is any arbitrary value.
For simplicity, let's take $k=0$. Now:
$$\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle = e_1 \, A \, e_1^T = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle = 0.$$
Therefore, I got the final answer as
$$\langle x, y \rangle = 2x_1y_2 + 2x_2y_1$$
I'm not sure if this is correct, and also I would like to know if there is any other method to solve it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Hint: your solution doesn't work because an inner product must satisfy $\langle x,x\rangle>0$ for any $x\ne0$, and yet you already noticed that $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle=\langle e_2,e_2\rangle=0$ in your attempt

Assuming $\,\{e_1,e_2\}\,$ is (the standard) basis for a vector space $\,V\,$ over the scalar field $\,\mathbb{R}\,$,
any inner product on $\,V\,$ can be defined by
$$
\langle u,v\rangle := v^T A\, u\ \ ,
$$
where $\,A\,$ is a self-adjoint and positive-definite matrix.
Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c &d\end{bmatrix}$ where $\,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\,$.
Since $\,A\,$ must be self-adjoint,
$$
A =  A^T\ \ \implies\ \ \begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c &d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a &c\\b &d\end{bmatrix} \ \ \implies \ \ c=b\ \ .
$$
On the other hand, we also know
$$
\langle e_1,e_2\rangle=2\ \ \implies\ \ \begin{bmatrix}0 &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\b &d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=2\ \ \implies\ \ b=2\ \ .
$$
Since $\,A\,$ is symmetric, it has Real eigenvalues, and positive-definiteness is equivalent to those eigenvalues being positive.
Recall that the $\,\operatorname{tr}(A)\,$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, and $\,\operatorname{det}(A)\,$ is the product of the eigenvalues. So, denoting the eigenvalues by $\,\lambda_1\,$ and $\,\lambda_2\,$ we have:
$$
\lambda_1\lambda_2=ad-4\quad\land\quad\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = a+d\ \ .
$$
Note that if both of these quantities are positive, then both $\,\lambda_1\,$ and $\,\lambda_2\,$ would have to be positive.
So at this point, to avoid doing messy algebra, simply let $\,a=1\,$ and see if you can find a value of $\,d\,$ that satisfies both conditions. For example, $\,a=1\,,d=5\,$ works.
